# Who is the healing mutant in first Egyptian scene of X-Men: Apocalypse

Tags: plot-explanation, character, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse

In *X-Men: Apocalypse* (2016). Who is the mutant (with instant healing power) in the first scene in Egypt, where En Sabah Nur's (Apocalypse) consciousness is being transferred to.

Does this character have any references in comics?

[image]

Comment: After searching the internet *a lot*, I don't think that the mutant exists outside of the movie or even was given a name in the movie.

Answer (score 2):

There is no instant healing mutant in that scene. What you are calling “healing” is the transference of life from Old Apocalypse to New Apocalypse (played by Oscar Isaac).

There is an old man mutant named “High Priest” in the script. He is played by the actor Al Maini. He is conducting the ceremony and causing the blue light to go from old body to new body.

[image: High Priest]

A young woman finishes the ceremony after the blue light is done moving from old Apocalypse to new Apocalypse. She moves Apocalypse’s armor from old body to new body with mutant powers. She is named “Horseman Death” in the script, and she is played by Monique Ganderton.

[image: horseman death]

Comment: IIRC before the transfer one of the priests cuts the recipient and we see the wound heal almost immediately. I believe this is suposed to be how Apocalypse accumulates powers, by transfering into mutants with new ones and taking them with him when he leaves. This is why he wants to transfer again in modern times, to get a new power.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what happens. The is completely incorrect.

Comment: I watched the scene about the 10 times to get this answer. I will watch again until I find what you are talking about and update the answer.